# Make my code color coded

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I would like to color parts of my VBA Code. Is that possible?
For example I would like to have colored cell references so that I can copy-paste code and find cell references faster in order to change them.

Thanks in advance!
/Niko

Comment: No you cant change the color of cell addresses in VBA editor.  Instead you can differentiate the font color of the Text entries with your desired font using Tools>>Options>>Editor Format>>Code Colors>>Normal Text>>Foreground>>Select your desired Color here.  (But ensure that your selected color should not conflict with the existing code colors which will make this process useless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the editor doesn't differentiate between a `Range()` method, a `Cells()` method or any other method. So if you change syntax highlighting for one you change it for all. The same with string arguments - it doesn't know that the string in `Range("A1:C5")` is a *range* argument - it just sees a string. So if you change the highlighting color for strings they will all change.